# When terminal is opened can I get current calendar and time displayed?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal I get a blank screen with a simplistic input prompt.

Is it possible (by modifying `~/.bashrc` perhaps) to display the current calendar with today highlighted and the current time?

If the time can be displayed in  large numbers (using figlet?) that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Improved Version

You can see the improved version here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1020693/307523

It looks like this:

[image: Terminal Splash Screen]

---

## Original Version

You can print an introduction banner when the terminal is opened using the `~/.bashrc` script. If you have figlet (`sudo apt install figlet`) you can take advantage of large letters to display the time:

[image: now]

In the first instance `figlet` is used to display the time and in the second a regular font is used.

### Additional screen examples using `toilet`

[image: now 3]

This screen uses fonts from the `toilet` package. The last example uses `future` font and is used in the code below. Additionally, the calendar is set to cyan color in the code below.

The `toilet` package allows additional font types and formatting styles over the `figlet` package which it is forked from. To install the package use `sudo apt install toilet` after installing `figlet` as described above.

## The code

Here is the code you need to make it all work. It's recommended to place this script in your `/home/user/bin` directory as it is automatically added to your path. This script is named `now` but you can use any unique name you like.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: now
# PATH: $HOME/bin
# DESC: Display current calendar and time
# CALL: Called from terminal or ~/.bashrc
# DATE: Apr 6, 2017. Modified: Apr 10, 2017.

# NOTE: To display all available toilet fonts use this one-liner:
#       for i in ${TOILET_FONT_PATH:=/usr/share/figlet}/*.{t,f}lf; do j=${i##*/}; toilet -d "${i%/*}" -f "$j" "${j%.*}"; done

# calendar current month with today higlighted.
# colors 00=bright white, 31=red, 32=green, 33=yellow, 34=blue, 35=purple,
#        36=cyan, 37=white
printf "\033[36m"       # color 36=cyan
echo ""; cal;
printf "\033[00m"       # color bright white (default)
echo ""

tput sc                 # Save cursor position.
# Move up 9 lines
while [ $((++i)) -lt 10 ]; do tput cuu1; done
tput cuf 25             # Move 25 columns right

# Do we have the toilet package?
if hash toilet 2>/dev/null; then
    echo " "$(date +"%I:%M %P")" " | \
        toilet -f future --filter border > /tmp/terminal
# Do we have the figlet package?
elif hash figlet 2>/dev/null; then
    echo $(date +"%I:%M %P") | figlet > /tmp/terminal
# else use standard font
else
    echo $(date +"%I:%M %P") > /tmp/terminal
fi

while IFS= read -r Time; do
    printf "\033[01;32m" # color green
    printf "$Time"
    tput cud1           # Up one line
    tput cuf 25         # Move 25 columns right
done < /tmp/terminal

tput rc                 # Restore saved cursor position.

exit 0
```

#### Mark script as executable

Copy this code into your editor and save it to the file `now`. Next mark it as executable using:

```bash
sudo chmod +x now
```

#### Add script to `~./bashrc`

Once this is completed you can type `now` in the terminal and you will see the calendar and time. To wrap it all up and have it automatically displayed each time you open the terminal:

- Edit the file `~/.bashrc`
- Go to the end and insert a new line containing `now`
- Save the file

Now when opening the terminal you will be greeted with the current day highlighted on current month's calendar followed by the current time.

### Dissecting the code

Here we'll briefly look at how the code works without discussing every line.

#### `figlet` and `toilet` packages

The script first checks if `toilet` is installed with the `hash` command. If so that is used to display time. If not `figlet` is used if installed. If neither are installed a regular font is used.

In the code above a comment can be copied to your command line and executed to show available `figlet` and `toilet` fonts on your terminal:

```bash
for i in ${TOILET_FONT_PATH:=/usr/share/figlet}/*.{t,f}lf; do j=${i##*/}; toilet -d "${i%/*}" -f "$j" "${j%.*}"; done
```

To change the font used for time display search the code for this line:

```bash
toilet -f future --filter border > /tmp/terminal
```

and change the font name `future` to the font name you choose. Keep in mind some fonts are too large to fit on the display.

#### Selecting colors

Set the color you want for the calendar and the time separately. In the above code, notice the command:

```bash
printf "\033[36m"       # color 36=cyan
```

Change the last two digits to the color code you want to use. From tinkering with the code I found these values:

> **00**=bright white, **31**=red, **32**=green, **33**=yellow, **34**=blue, **35**=purple, **36**=cyan, **37**=white

If you find additional color codes please post a comment below or update this answer.

Comment: The bashrc shouldn't produce any output (though I can't remember the reason why). So instead of just `now`, it may be better to put this line in it: `PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $now_already_run != yes ]] && now_already_run=yes && now'`

Comment: @wjandrea The closest I could find is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440287/scp-doesnt-work-when-echo-in-bashrc however it has a different solution. Let's leave our comments here until someone reports a problem that can be reproduced and then fix it?

Comment: There's certainly a niche case where running a command with `bash -ic <command>` produces unexpected output, but I can't think of a situation where that would be a problem.

Comment: Colors are ANSI escape sequences. More info and a list here: http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: Very nice. Maybe overkill for my taste but very impressive

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple time and date you can add these to the end of your .bashrc:

```
echo -e "Welcome to [$(hostname)] You are logged in as user [$USER]"
echo -e "Local time: [$(date)]"
```

which will display the following when you login:

```
Welcome to [deathstar] You are logged in as user [skywalker]
[Local time]: Sun Apr 9 10:18:11 CDT 2017.
```

I have a python [script](https://github.com/xajnx/bashwx) I wrote that will add local weather and your WAN and LAN IPs to your .bashrc file as well. Set a cronjob to update the weather. It comes with a sample .bashrc also

It will display:

```
Welcome to [deathstar] You are logged in as user [skywalker]
[Local time]: Sun Apr  9 10:18:11 CDT 2017.
[Local weather]: 68.68 F with few clouds
[Your public IP is]: 1.2.3.4 [Local IP]: 192.168.2.6
```

If you want to take it a step further you can add extra [colors and formatting](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) to make your values match your profile